# Java - Access For Loop Counter From Inside Anonymous Class

Tags: java

i have a for loop which is adding menuItems to a menu. After adding each menu item, i want to add an actionlistener to it, so when clicked in the menu it will load the corresponding index item from an array. The problem is java will not allow me to call arraylist.get(i) from the anonymous action listener class, as it sais i must be final. i cannot make i final as it increments on each iteration. can anybody help? cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not extract the element as a `final` reference outside the anonymous class ?

```
for (int i = 0: i < list.size(); i++) {
   final elem = list.get(i);
   // now use it...
}
```

Note this is safer for another reason. In your original solution you're going back to the list and that could potentially change, such that your anonymous class could extract a different object on each callback. In this variant it's given the `final` reference to the actual instance.

Comment: Thankyou very much, i was stuck on this for a while

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your ActionListener as public class and pass the required menu items in its constructor.